# Where is the vscode setting governing this weird extra-space newline indentation when you have a closing bracket on the line?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, auto-indent

I've been using VScode for a while - and have been experiencing a weird extra space recently (anecdotally since I've upgraded to the most recent version).

So, this happens when editing python if there is a closing bracket and I hit enter to move text to the next line:

1. The text will go to the *correct* place based the indentation guide settings
2. pause for a second to laugh at me
3. Then add an extra space.

This doesn't happen if there isn't a closing bracket, but is annoying because the closing bracket is auto-added when I put in the opening bracket, and so this happens way more often than it should.

So, I start with this:

```py
def function():
    cases = pq.read_table(
        "filename.parquet",
        columns = ["docket_number"]
```

Press enter, and then I get (dots are spaces, but added to highlight the issue):

```py
def function():
    cases = pq.read_table(
        "filename.parquet",
        columns = [
        ....."docket_number"]
```

And the indent should be 4. If there wasn't a closing bracket, it correctly give me this:

```py
def function():
    cases = pq.read_table(
        "filename.parquet",
        columns = [
        ...."docket_number"
```

So, what the heck governs this?

Comment: Where is your cursor when you press enter?

Comment: @JonSG, before the quote at the beginning of `"docket_number"]` - i.e. `columns = [<CURSOR>"docket_number"]`

Comment: Hey, that looks like the indentation I would expect then as `columns` is a list.  What indentation did you expect?

Comment: Do you have any formatting extensions installed other than **Python**? Show your workspace and user *settings.json`, I deleted all the settings and it didn't happen what you said. Probably one of your settings is causing it to happen.  Also is the test code the entire contents of the script? Because if there are other codes in the context, the formatting may also be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have `editor.formatOnType` enabled, turn it off (untick it),

[image]

or add the following in *settings.json*

```json
    "editor.formatOnType": false,
```

Comment: This worked... eventually.  There are multiple settings for "Format on type" and apparently the one was set in `User[Python]` and overriding the unset ones upstream. 

Thanks much!